# Sort a string containing strings and integers such that the strings are in alphabetical order and all integers are numerical in order

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

Sample Input : "car truck 8 4 bus 6 1"

Sample Output : "bus car 1 4 truck 6 8"

If the nth element in the string is an integer it must remain an integer,
and if it is a word it must remain a word

Is there a more elegant and efficient way of doing this? Below is my ruby code. I am looking for code which is more efficient(need not be in ruby).

```
puts "Enter Input:"
inp = gets

inp_ary=inp.split(" ")

a=inp_ary.group_by{|i| i=~ /\d/}

sort_words = a[nil].sort
sort_integer = a[0].sort

index_words=[]
index_integer=[]

inp_ary.each_with_index do |e,i|
  if e =~ /\d/
    index_integer << i
  else
    index_words << i
  end
end

final = []

sorted = sort_words + sort_integer

index_integer.each_with_index do |e,i|
  final[e] = sort_integer[i]
end

index_words.each_with_index do |e,i|
  final[e] = sort_words[i]
end

puts "Sorted Output: "
puts final.join(" ")
```

Comment: Because c++ is most efficient language ever? :-) More interesting is why truck is between 4 and 6.

Comment: What position should integers have with respect to words ? i.e. why is 4 after car but before truck?

Comment: I edited the question and added the condition for the position of integers and string. "If the nth element in the list is an integer it must remain an integer, and if it is a word it must remain a word"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "car truck 8 4 bus 6 1"

tokens = s.split
numbers, words = tokens.partition{|t| t =~ /^\d+$/}
numbers.map!(&:to_i).sort!
words.sort!

result = tokens.map{|t| (t =~ /^\d+$/ ? numbers : words).shift}.join(' ')

p result
#=> "bus car 1 4 truck 6 8"
```